# Including Socket.io on the client-side

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I've been spending all day working on my first app incorporating socket.io with Node and Express and I cannot seem to locate my `socket.io.js` file on the client side. I've read many SO questions and other forums about this issue, but can't seem to get mine to work with any of the recommended solutions.

I have installed express and socket.io successfully and everything is working fine on the server side (currently just got it working with the Twitter Stream Api). Now that I want to use the data from `emit` on the client side I need to include my socket file.

I've got HoganJS setup as my view engine.

Here is an excerpt from my `app.js` file:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.cookieParser('your secret here'));
app.use(express.session());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: path.join(__dirname, 'public') }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

I have another file called `index.js` which is where my twitter and socket code is,here is my require lines:

```
var twitter = require('ntwitter');
var io = require('socket.io').listen(3001, {log: false});
// all my twitter setup/functions etc here
io.sockets.emit('tweets' ,data);
```

Now on the client side, I've tried every possible path I can think of including:

```
<script src="localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And many other paths trying to figure out how to link it in properly. I'm terribly sorry if this is obvious or answered elsewhere, but I couldn't find it.

Any path I can come up with results in a 404 according to chrome dev tools.

Thanks so much!

Comment: are you saying the script src  .js files are the ones that 404?  If so have you tried a blank HTML file which has just those lines and see if you get the same error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running `socket.io` on port 3001:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

But you can also run `socket.io` and Express on the same port together:

```
var express = require('express');
var app     = express();
var server  = app.listen(3000);
var io      = require('socket.io').listen(server);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Can't believe I missed that, you're a life saver haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have file `socket.io.js` or not.

check under `node_modules -> socket.io -> socket.io.js`

If yes then try this path

`< script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" > < /script>`